# Plotting trends and predictions data from OLS (statsmodels)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, linear-regression, statsmodels

I have this data from 1992 to 2016:

```
            Year month  data    stdBS   index1
1992-05-01  1992    5   302.35  31.69   727319
1992-06-01  1992    6   305.07  27.59   727350
1992-07-01  1992    7   297.12  29.12   727380
1992-08-01  1992    8   304.39  21.41   727411
1992-09-01  1992    9   294.30  32.26   727442
```

Using this code:

```
flow2=fmO['data']
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(6,4))  
res2 = sm.tsa.seasonal_decompose(flow2)
residual = res2.resid
seasonal = res2.seasonal
trend = res2.trend
fig = res2.plot()  
plt.show()
```

I obtained this plot:

[image]

Everything is fine, but now I need to plot the predictions fit

```
trend2 = trend.reset_index()
X = fm0.index1
y = trend
X = sm.add_constant(X)
model = sm.OLS(y,X, missing='drop')
results = model.fit()
predictions = results.predict(X)
p = results.summary()
```

With this short code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,4))
ax.scatter(df0.index, trend)
ax.plot(df0.index, df0.predic, 'r')
ax.set_ylabel('Data')
```

I obtained this plot:

[image]

But I lost the index of the original trend plot. My question is if there exists some simple way to plot trend data from `sm.tsa.seasonal_decompose` with the linear fit predictions with the original index time?

Comment: hey I need to do the same thing.But I am getting an error.Can you help?I just need the stats and not plot. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50504357/how-to-find-out-the-slope-value-by-applying-linear-regression-on-trend-of-a-data